# RABBITMQ send messages to LOGSTASH

Tags: rabbitmq, logstash, logstash-configuration

can you help me with RabbitMQ input in logstash.
My application sending versions of code to rabbitmq and then it go to store in elastic stack.
For app in rabbitmq was created queue
name: app_version_queue;
type: classic;
durable: true

Then logstash was configured with that config:

```
input {
  rabbitmq {
    id => "rabbitmyq_id"
    # connect to rabbit
    host => "localhost"
    port => 5672
    vhost => "/"
    # INPUT - PRODUCERS
    key => "app_version_queue"
    # OUTPUT - CONSUMER
    # queue for logstash
    queue => "logstash"
    auto_delete => false
    # Exchange for logstash
    exchange => logstash
    exchange_type => direct
    durable => "true"
    # No ack will boost your perf
    ack => false
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "elasticsearch:9200" ]
    index => "app_version-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

It's worked, but now, in RabbitMQ console, i see in table Queued messages
Ready: 914,444
Unacked: 0
Total: 914,444

And my disk space on rabbitmq cluster go to full in 3 days.
After rebooting rabbitmq server, all space is free.

UPDATED:
All reason, why i do that, i want to remove NIFI from that chain app=>rabbit=>nifi=>elastic
I want to do: app=>rabbit=>logstash=>elastic

1. Queue: app_version
   My application send messages to nifi=>ELASTIC
   [Queue1 - app_version_queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWGEo.png)
2. Queue: logstash, what i created with logstash
   [Queue2 - logstash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3076J.png)

I try to stop NIFI sending, but messages not leaving.

Comment: Given that the messages aren't being consumed from the queue, what makes you think "it worked"? Are you seeing the messages appear in ElasticSearch? If so, there must be a second queue somewhere that it's consuming them from.

Comment: yes, i see messages in elasticsearch. Hm, so my messages handled another queue, it's a reason, why they dont deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what's happened is you've created the infrastructure twice:

- Once manually in RabbitMQ
- Once in the configuration options to LogStash

What you need is **just three things**:

- An exchange for the application to publish messages to.
- A queue for LogStash to consume messages from.
- A binding between that exchange and that queue; the queue will get a **copy** of every message published to the exchange with a matching routing key.

What you have is **all of this**:

- An exchange called `logs` (created manually) which your application publishes messages to.
- A queue called `app_version_queue` (created manually) which nothing consumes from.
- A binding (created manually) delivering copies of messages from `logs` into `app_version_queue`, which then sit there forever.
- An exchange called `logstash` (created by LogStash) which nothing publishes messages to.
- A queue called `logstash` (created by LogStash) which LogStash consumes messages from.
- A binding (created by LogStash) from the `logstash` exchange to the `logstash` queue which doesn't do anything, because no messages are published to that exchange.
- A binding (created manually) from the `logs` exchange to the `logstash` queue which is actually delivering the messages from your application.

So, for each of the three things (the exchange, the queue, and the binding) you need to:

- Decide a name
- Decide if you're creating it, or letting LogStash create it
- Configure everything to use the same name

For instance, you could keep the names `logs` and `app_version_queue`, and create everything manually.

Then your LogStash application would look something like this:

```
input {
  rabbitmq {
    id => "rabbitmyq_id"
    # connect to rabbit
    host => "localhost"
    port => 5672
    vhost => "/"
    # Consume from existing queue
    queue => "app_version_queue"
    # No ack will boost your perf
    ack => false
  }
}
```

On the other hand, you could create just the `logs` exchange, and let LogStash create the queue and binding, like this:

```
input {
  rabbitmq {
    id => "rabbitmyq_id"
    # connect to rabbit
    host => "localhost"
    port => 5672
    vhost => "/"
    # Create a new queue
    queue => "logstash_processing_queue"
    durable => "true"
    # Take a copy of all messages with the "app_version_queue" routing key from the existing exchange
    exchange => "logs"
    key => "app_version_queue"
    # No ack will boost your perf
    ack => false
  }
}
```

Or you could let LogStash create *all* of it, and make sure your application publishes to the right exchange:

```
input {
  rabbitmq {
    id => "rabbitmyq_id"
    # connect to rabbit
    host => "localhost"
    port => 5672
    vhost => "/"
    # Create a new queue
    queue => "logstash_processing_queue"
    durable => "true"
    # Create a new exchange; point your application to publish here!
    exchange => "log_exchange"
    exchange_type => "direct"
    # Take a copy of all messages with the "app_version_queue" routing key from the new exchange
    key => "app_version_queue"
    # No ack will boost your perf
    ack => false
  }
}
```

I'd probably go with the middle option: the exchange is a part of the application's deployment requirements (it will produce errors if it can't publish there), but any number of queues might bind to it for different reasons (maybe none at all in a test environment, where you don't need ElasticSearch set up).

Comment: thx you man!, you rly saved me), i try to check it with 2 input.